# Why is Completeness needed to demonstrate the Archimedean principle?

Tags: analysis

Why is Completeness needed to demonstrate the Archimedean principle?

Could someone criticize the following proof.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Proof**

Considering any $x \in \mathbb{R},$ $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \in \mathbb{N},$ and $$0 \leq x - \lfloor{x}\rfloor < 1$$

and

$$x < \lfloor{x}\rfloor + 1.$$

Given that $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \in \mathbb{N},$ $\lfloor{x}\rfloor + 1 \in \mathbb{N}.$ Hence, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x < n.$

Comment: How do you define $\lfloor x\rfloor$?  How do you know it exists?

Comment: Isn't it a well-defined function whose domain is the entirety of the real numbers?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions: "the floor function is the function that takes as input a real number $x$ and gives as output the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$"

Comment: $\lfloor{x}\rfloor = \operatorname{max}\{m \in \mathbb{Z} : m \leq x\}$

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud That definition rather presupposes the Archimedean property. It assumes that there is a **greatest** integer $\le x$. Why cannot all integers be $\le x$?

Comment: The fact that any real number is in between two consecutive integers follows from the Archimedean property. You cannot even define the floor without it.

Comment: Ya. I understand. Thank you

Comment: I suppose I was not thinking of it at first in terms of "max" but more in truncating the decimals (that may or may not exist) to arrive at the integer just under it, and adding one, but now that I see "max" necessarily in the formal definition of the function and the feedback you guys gave, it makes sense. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why completeness is needed? Here are two ordered fields that aren't complete, one with the Archimedean property and one without:

$\mathbb{Q}$ is an ordered field with the property.

Construct an order on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ (the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{R}$) as follows: a fraction $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ with $Q$ monic is positive when the leading coefficient of $P$ is positive. In terms of function values, a rational function $f$ is positive when there is some $M$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>M$.
With this order, $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is an ordered field that doesn't have the Archimedean property. $x$ is an element that's greater than every integer, and $\frac1x$ is an element that's smaller than the reciprocal of every positive integer.

If we can construct examples without that completeness axiom in which the property doesn't hold, that means we need that axiom to prove the property.

Answer (score 1):

The reals inherit the Archimedean property from the rational numbers.

Fix real $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists a rational $\frac{p}{q}$ as close as we wish to $\varepsilon$. For example, we could choose one so that the following holds (Here we use that $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$).

$$0<\frac{p}{q}\le\varepsilon$$

Then define $N:=q$ and observe that by multiplying it on all sides we obtain

$$0<p\le \varepsilon N$$

Which is to say, for each real $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $1<\varepsilon N$. This is precisely the Archimedean property.